# Adding a gradient to a border or stackpanel silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How do i add a bit of a gradient to a border or stackpanel so the front part of it looks like it has a bit of a gradient or a curve making it look a bit 3d

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom LinearGradientBrush for the border like so

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" x:Key="MyBorderBrush">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

To apply the border you add a border brush to the border

```
<Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
    <!-- Content -->
</Border>
```